# Simple drag and drop swift/xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, drag-and-drop

Try to use the drag and drop function within swift xcode. Here is what i am trying to achieve..

I am trying to create a game where a child has to sequence numbers in the correct order. Therefore i want the user to be able to select an image and drag it across the screen and place it on top of an shadow image.

Can anyone help me with the drag and drop function within xcode

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Read more here: [UIPangestureRecognizer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer).

Note that it has different states (`.began`, `.ended`, etc.), which you can use to detect when the view is "grabbed", "move around" and "dropped".

To detect which view was grabbed (or if the grab was inside a view), you might find this useful:

```swift
let view = gestureRecognizer.view
let loc = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
let subview = view?.hitTest(loc, with: nil) // note: it is a UIView?
```

As marked in the comment, the subview can be nil, so you should check if it exists before using it.